# Embedding a html document inside of RST

Tags: python, html, django, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have a Sphinx-based website and have specific pages on which I would like to display predefined html files that are stored in a specified directory like _static. In Django, it's possible to simply reference the file from the template using an {{%include}} tag, does something similar exist for ReStructuredText?

I would like to do something like

```
.. title:: Example Page

=============
Example Page
=============

Introduction to page

<insert html reference to _static folder here>

Description
```

And after building the website have it combine the html generated from RST and the html file specified.

Answer (score 2):

From the docutils [docs for the `raw` directive](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#raw-data-pass-through):

> Raw data can also be read from an external file, specified in a directive option. In this case, the content block must be empty. For example:
>
> ```
> .. raw:: html
>     :file: inclusion.html
> ```
>
> Inline equivalents of the "raw" directive can be defined via [custom interpreted text roles](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#custom-interpreted-text-roles) derived from the ["raw" role](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/roles.html#raw).
>
> The following options are recognized:
>
> `file` : *string (newlines removed)*
> The local filesystem path of a raw data file to be included.

If you are embedding only *snippets* and not *complete valid HTML pages*, then that is what you want to use.  For the latter, you can still use `raw`, but use an `<iframe>`:

```
.. raw:: html

    <iframe src="inclusion.html"></iframe>
```